# How can I improve this query with Django ORM?

Tags: python, django

I have a `Person` model with `name` and `city` as attributes. I need a way to retrieve the amount of people by city. I need an output like this dictionary: `{"NY": 23, "CA": 30, ...}`

What I did was:

```
response = {}
for city in ["NY", "CA", ...]:
    response[city] = Person.objects.filter(city=city).count()
```

Here I have to provide a predefined list with cities and iterate over them. Does there exist any way to do this directly with Django ORM and avoid the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do

```
response = dict(Person.objects.values('city').\
                       annotate(count=Count('city')).\
                       values_list('city', 'count'))
```

#### UPDATE

As OP correctly noted, you can omit `.values('city')`:

```
response = dict(Person.objects.annotate(count=Count('city')).\
                       values_list('city', 'count'))
```

Comment: It is necessary the first part: .values('city')? This is not the same: dict(Person.objects.annotate(count=Count('city')).values_list('city', 'count'))?

Comment: @mos yeah, you're right, you can omit `.values('city')`.

Comment: It should be `Person.objects.values_list('city').annotate(...)`. Annotated attributes are automatically added to the output fields, but [the order of annotate and values/values_list matters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/aggregation/#order-of-annotate-and-values-clauses).

Answer (score 1):

So to solve this problem, I basically go back to barebone SQL. You want something like this:

```
SELECT city, count(*) FROM person
WHERE city in (...)
GROUP BY 1
```

Then try to search, how to make aggregated params in [django ORM](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/aggregation/):

```
from django.db.models import Count
Person.objects.filter(city__in=cities).annotate(count=Count('city'))
```